# Anyone Know "How to connect Power Bi Cloud version with Netsuite via ODBC ?"

Tags: odbc, powerbi, netsuite, powerbi-desktop, cdata-drivers

I am new to Power Bi cloud version, I need to connect power Bi with Netsuite(version 2018.2).As i am able to connect Power Bi Deskop with Netsuite using ODBC connection.But for **Power bi Cloud** version i am not getting how to do the ODBC connection.Please help me to know this.

Comment: You can use the [Power BI On-premises data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem) to do this.

Comment: You tagged CData, so this specific article may be useful: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/netsuite-powerbi-gateway.rst